# Webscraping results to data frame

Tags: python

Im in the process of trying to figure out how to take my scraped data and convert it to a dataframe using pandas,

I scraped data off a grocery website as an experiment. Using Beautiful soup, once I import the URL and use beautiful soup  I then created a loop to pull anything within a certain class with div tags. Then i used the code below to pull the data below:

```
import urllib2
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pickle

link=requests.get("https://www.iga.net/en/online_grocery/frozen_grocery")
soup = BeautifulSoup(link.content, 'html.parser')
##print soup.prettify()
bowl=soup.find_all('div',class_='js-product js-equalized js-addtolist-container js-ga')

for bowls in bowl:
    list=bowls.get('data-product')
    print list
```

list printed:

```
{'ProductId':'00000_000000005500059917','BrandName':'Nestle','FullDisplayName':'10 Pack Mini Rolo Bars','IsAgeRequired':false,'SizeLabel':'','Size':'10 x 45 ml','ProductUrl':'/en/product/mini-rolo-bars10-pack/00000_000000005500059917','ProductImageUrl':'https://az836796.vo.msecnd.net/media/image/product/en/medium/0005500059917.jpg','HasNewPrice':false,'PromotionName':null,'RegularPrice':6.49000,'SalesPrice':null}
{'ProductId':'00000_000000005574253356','BrandName':'Compliments','FullDisplayName':'100% Pure Frozen Concentrate Pulp Free Juice','IsAgeRequired':false,'SizeLabel':'','Size':'283 ml','ProductUrl':'/en/product/juice100--pure-frozen-concentrate-pulp-free/00000_000000005574253356','ProductImageUrl':'https://az836796.vo.msecnd.net/media/image/product/en/medium/0005574253356.jpg','HasNewPrice':false,'PromotionName':null,'RegularPrice':1.79000,'SalesPrice':null}
```

I'm trying to take the productID, size and regular price for example and dump that into a table. I'd even be ok to take the entire keys and values and dump them into a data frame so i can play around with it in excel.

I've tried to do the following but i get an error (added in the data frame in the last block:

```
import urllib2
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pickle

link=requests.get("https://www.iga.net/en/online_grocery/frozen_grocery")
soup = BeautifulSoup(link.content, 'html.parser')
##print soup.prettify()
bowl=soup.find_all('div',class_='js-product js-equalized js-addtolist-container js-ga')

for bowls in bowl:
    list=bowls.get('data-product')
    df = pd.DataFrame(list)
    print df
```

This results in an error. Any help is appreciated. I'm a rookie to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need convert each `data-product` to be a valid python dictionary, then merge all of them to one dictionary, after that, you can convert to dataframe like this:

```
import urllib2
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pickle
import json
import collections

link=requests.get("https://www.iga.net/en/online_grocery/frozen_grocery")
soup = BeautifulSoup(link.content, 'html.parser')
##print soup.prettify()
bowl=soup.find_all('div',class_='js-product js-equalized js-addtolist-container js-ga')

super_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)

for bowls in bowl:
    data=bowls.get('data-product')
    data = data.replace("\'","\"") #json.loads accepts only double quotes for json properties, so replace ' with "
    dict_data = json.loads(data) #convert to valid python dictionary 
    for k, v in dict_data.iteritems():  # d.items() in Python 3+
        super_dict[k].append(v) #merge all dictionary
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(super_dict))
df
```

Output will be the dataframe you want:

[image]

**Update:**

if you want to view the dataframe in excel file, you can write to excel file with below code:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Then you can open file `pandas_simple.xlsx` to check the data in excel format.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful. I'll need to go through the code to better understand it. Is there a way to create a data frame in a way that all the headings go along top with the data below? like an excel sheet?

Comment: Yes, the dataframe is created like the excel sheet, column names will be the header, here is the dictionary's keys like 'ProductId','BrandName', etc, and the data will be the dictionary's values.

Comment: You can check the updated answer, which shows the result of dataframe

Comment: hi there when i execute the code, nothing happens. I don't get the dataframe like how you have it. I changed df at the end to print df and the data is all over the place...if i use df nothing happens. thoughts?

Comment: my code is running in jupyter notebook, when df it will show the dataframe format, I think you are running in other terminal, right?

Comment: you can try to write the df to excel file to see all the data, check the answer's update.

Comment: I'm running mine in textwrangler using macOS

Comment: well, I didn't use macOS... maybe you can try to write the df into excel file like above mentioned, then you can open the excel file to check the data

Comment: @SKS81 great, glad to hear that. If the answer is helpful, please mark it as an accept answer, thanks :)